# Is there a way to avoid javascript audio hiccuping while your program is loading other media at the same time?

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm building a WebGL program where the scene changes at certain intervals. The scene change consists of destroying the previous scene, and loading up a new one, which means loading some texture files along with it.

At the same time, I'm also playing some audio throughout the program, that should keep playing during the destroy scene/create scene process. The program works fine, but I notice that when I'm loading the new scene with the new assets, the audio hiccups right before all of the new assets are finished loading.

Is there anything I can possibly do to prevent the small hiccup during the new load? I don't think its a file size issue, or an audio buffer issue, since all of the assets including the audio are pretty small (500k or less).

Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: _"since all of the assets including the audio are pretty small (500k or less)"_ Do you change the audio source?

Comment: @guest271314 I continuously play a single overarching source, and then each scene has it's own background loop that plays underneath it which loads and destroys with the scene change. Do you think it could be the additional audio?

Comment: Given description of issue, without being able to reproduce, that is a logical conclusion which could be reached.

Answer (score 1):

The hiccup was caused by the heavy javascript processes during the switch and was interrupting the audio. I managed to fix this issue by using the Web Audio API instead of the javascript Audio() object, which allowed the audio to play in a different context than what the program was running in.